# How to check a non verified URI status in the SophosLabs Intelix URL Lookup API?

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

I've submitted a phishing url to URL LOOKUP API and got this response (with some characters replaced with 'X'):

`{"requestId": "8d07XXXXX-b0X5-X4gX-3XaX-XXXXXX677acXX,XXXXXXXXX76", "ttl": 300}`

Nothing about `productivityCategory`, `securityCategory` or `riskLevel`.

It's possible to check for more information with `requestId` provided in request response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the URL is unknown by SophosLabs Intelix at the moment, even if it has a huge database.
requestId only used for tracking a single request, no further data can be queried. 
BTW how did you find out that is a phising URL?
Could you please share with me?